# JanusGraph cluster always returns vertex without properties (ReferenceVertex)

Tags: cluster-computing, gremlin, gremlin-server, janusgraph

I've problem with janusgraph gremlin-server and Cluster client.
Vertices retrieved using Cluster (gremlin-driver 3.2.3/3.2.5) only contains id attribute, label and properties always empty.

This is my client config.

```
val cluster = Cluster.open("/opt/janusgraph-0.1.1-hadoop2/conf/remote-objects.yaml")
```

remote-objects.yaml

```
hosts: [localhost] 
   port: 8182
   serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
```

gremlin-server config:

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/gremlin-server/graph.properties}
plugins:
  - janusgraph.imports
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    imports: [java.lang.Math],
    staticImports: [java.lang.Math.PI],
    scripts: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0, config: {ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV2d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  gangliaReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000, addressingMode: MULTICAST},
  graphiteReporter: {enabled: false, interval: 180000}}
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
ssl: {enabled: false}
```

Remote queries using gremlin-console working fine (remote.yaml and remote-objects.yaml)

Queries using Cluster and remote traversals don't work:

```
val g = EmptyGraph.instance().traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "g"))

g.V().toList.foreach(v => println(v, "id", v.id(), "label", v.label(), v.properties("name").toList, v.getClass))
```

Output:

```
(v[8336],id,8336,label,,List(),class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceVertex)
(v[12288],id,12288,label,,List(),class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceVertex)
(v[12304],id,12304,label,,List(),class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceVertex)
(v[12328],id,12328,label,,List(),class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceVertex)
(v[12360],id,12360,label,,List(),class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.reference.ReferenceVertex)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with a remote graph like you've attempted, you will get back `ReferenceElements` which have minimal information included with them. Unfortunately, there are not a lot of docs on this at the moment (I've [opened a ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-1755) to address this), but you can refer to this [mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/fovFrer7hUU/hpsXndHbBAAJ).

The remote traversals are working fine, but you should be more explicit in what you request. For example, if you want the `id`, `label`, and all `properties`, you could use:

```
g.V().valueMap(true).toList()
```

Comment: this will return the list of the map of properties. Instead of returning a list of vertices. I need to get list of vertices which contains all the properties